# webpack not bundling properly

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using web pack for bundling. I am getting the following error

> TypeError: The value of the superclass's prototype property is not an object.

**app.js**

```
const MyOncogene = require('./my-oncogene');

require("../css/style.css");

new MyOncogene({})
```

**my-oncogene.js**

```
const Oncogene = require('./lib.oncogene');

module.export = class MyOncogene extends Oncogene {}
```

**lib.oncogene.js**

```
class Oncogene {}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'docs')
  },
   module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [ 'css-loader' ]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css'
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not exporting the Oncogene class. You should write at the end of lib.oncogene:

```
module.exports = Oncogene;
```

Additionally in my-oncogene you are writing `module.export` instead of `module.exports`